# PHP PDO always give only one result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wrote a SQL query with PDO. DB table has 3 results with match the query. But the PDO shows only one result.

my code is this

**conn.php**

```
function connect() {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbname = "guiding_db";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $conn;
}
```

**_admin.php**

```
include_once './conn.php';

function getStudentsRequests(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE signas = 'student' AND accept='0'";


   $result = connect()->query($sql);
   $out = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   print_r($out);
   return $out;

}

getStudentsRequests();
```

Comment: What is the value of `print_r($out);`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) loads a single row only. Use [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to load all rows (or use a `while` loop):

```
$out = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` method return only one row from query. If you want all you need to use `while` loop or `fetchAll` method

Answer (score 0):

[fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method return next result (one). If you wish get all results - use methods like [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php)